# GreenDao doesn't create foreign key?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys, greendao

I'm just start to learning this ORM, so maybe I've done something wrong. In entity I write OneToOne relation but greendao doesn't generate it. If I'm writing in entity constructor arguments for foreign key it just ignores this and makes it like this. So there is no property and column in table. Thank you.

Public:

```
@Entity(active = true)
public class Public {

@Id(autoincrement = true)
Long id;

int publicId;

@ToOne(joinProperty = "id")
private Category category;  ...

@Generated(hash = 12945501)
public Public(Long id, int publicId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.publicId = publicId;
}
```

PublicDao:

```
public class PublicDao extends AbstractDao<Public, Long> {

public static final String TABLENAME = "PUBLIC";

/**
 * Properties of entity Public.<br/>
 * Can be used for QueryBuilder and for referencing column names.
 */
public static class Properties {
    public final static Property Id = new Property(0, Long.class, "id", true, "_id");
    public final static Property PublicId = new Property(1, int.class, "publicId", false, "PUBLIC_ID");
}    ...

/** Creates the underlying database table. */
public static void createTable(Database db, boolean ifNotExists) {
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "\"PUBLIC\" (" + //
            "\"_id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," + // 0: id
            "\"PUBLIC_ID\" INTEGER NOT NULL );"); // 1: publicId
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake. I should to add another field for it, and to write it in joinProperty.